# Can i deploy more than one war files in a Mobile First (Worklight) server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have installed Mobile first Server (not the development server that comes with eclipse)

I have created a project in eclipse with 2 applications. Then i deployed the war file using the configuration tool. And finally i uploaded the wlapp files using the worklight web console. Everything is ok but i have one question:

Should I deploy a different war each time i create an application in a different project in eclipse? Should i create all apps under the same project, so no other war should be deployed? How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can deploy different war files so MobileFirst runtimes in the same application server. The context root of course must be different for each war.
In the MobileFirst console you will see the different runtimes deployed in your application server. Then for deploying the applications/adapters you have to select one runtime.
If you put applications under a project in Eclipse you could deploy the applications under another project but only in some circumstances (several projects using the same security tests for example or no security defined). But it is better to deploy all the applications on the project where they are created. Because for example you could reference in your application security tests or push notifications that don't exist in the runtime where they are deployed.

Comment: thank you for your answer. so to make it clear in my mind... Project (war files) contain server configuration. So i can have many of them. Also i can deploy wherever i want but i should take care to put together in the same project all apps that need to have the same server configuration. Right?

Comment: You are right. The war files contain especially the security configuration in the authenticationConfig.xml file and the SMS Gateway configuration for the notifications that can be used by the applications deployed in the project.